# execute ansible playbook for next host after finishing one host not all forked hosts

Tags: ansible, fork

With the fork variable I can tell ansible how many hosts should pe executed in parallel. The next hosts are executed when all hosts from before finished. In case the execution time differs on the hosts, I have to wait for the last host finishing.

Is it possible to tell ansible start the next play for one host after one has finished, not all running.

In other words, I have hundreds clients with a play running at 5 minutes and some hosts need 30 minutes. We tested the amount of fork and found that 50 is a good value. Sometimes the next 50 had to wait for one host 25 minutes.

Comment: Possibly setting the [play strategy to "free"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#selecting-a-strategy) will do what you want.

Comment: This will decouple only the consecutive started plays. The plays are executed as fast as they can, but no new play is started until all running plays finished.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *"**Is it possible to tell Ansible to start the next play for one host after one has finished?**"*

**A**: Yes. It's possible. The strategy plugin [host_pinned](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/strategy/host_pinned.html#host-pinned-executes-tasks-on-each-host-without-interruption) is what you're looking for. Quoting:

> *Ansible will not wait for other hosts to finish the current task before queuing the next task for a host that has finished. Once a host is done with the play, it opens its slot to a new host that was waiting to start.*

**Example**

Lets' create an inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    test_01:
      wait_timeout: 1
    test_02:
      wait_timeout: 2
    test_03:
      wait_timeout: 3
    test_06:
      wait_timeout: 4
    test_09:
      wait_timeout: 5
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pinned-01.yml
- name: Play A
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  strategy: host_pinned
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "A:{{ inventory_hostname }}
              {{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%H-%M-%S') }}
              started"
    - wait_for:
        timeout: "{{ wait_timeout }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "A:{{ inventory_hostname }}
              {{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%H-%M-%S') }}
              finished"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pinned-01.yml -f 3 | grep msg\":
    "msg": "A:test_06 15-33-05 started"
    "msg": "A:test_09 15-33-05 started"
    "msg": "A:test_01 15-33-05 started"
    "msg": "A:test_01 15-33-08 finished"
    "msg": "A:test_02 15-33-08 started"
    "msg": "A:test_06 15-33-11 finished"
    "msg": "A:test_03 15-33-11 started"
    "msg": "A:test_02 15-33-11 finished"
    "msg": "A:test_09 15-33-12 finished"
    "msg": "A:test_03 15-33-15 finished"
```

**Results**

Because of `-f 3` Ansible started 3 hosts (1,9,6). Host 1 finished first and opened its slot to a new host that was waiting to start. Host 2 started. The same way host 3 started right after host 6 finished. Host 2, which started after host 9, finished before host 9.

Comment: The documantation described exactly what I need, but it dosn't work as expected. The host_pinned strategy works like free. Ansible waits until all plays are finished, and starts then the next bulk of plays.

Comment: Works for me. I've updated the answer with the complete example. If you have trouble, update the question with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) details.

Comment: Yes, it works for me too. I found the problem: in the playbook I used the keyword serial instead of fork in ansible.cfg and this sets the strategy back to free. The usage of host_pinned gave a significant time reduction.

Comment: Right. `serial` and `fork` are different constructs.